# Column specifier cm{10mm} does not horizontally and vertically align text in a cell

Tags: tables, beamer, horizontal-alignment, vertical-alignment, alignment

I want a slide with a table of 5 columns. Each column width should be 10mm. The text in each cell should be both vertically and horizontally centered.

Code:

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\usepackage{array}
\usepackage{booktabs}
\begin{document}

\begin{frame}
\begin{tabular}{| cm{10mm} | cm{10mm} | cm{10mm} | cm{10mm} | cm{10mm} |}
\toprule
foo &
bar &
baz &
qux &
end \\
\midrule
foo bar baz qux &
foo bar baz qux &
foo bar baz qux &
foo bar baz qux &
foo bar baz qux \\
\bottomrule
\end{tabular}
\end{frame}

\end{document}
```

This is the output:

[image]

Wh is the table so broken? How can I fix it so that each cell is both vertically and horizontally centered?

Comment: `cm{10cm}` specifies two columns not one

Comment: ...So you need `>{\centering\arraybackslash}m{10mm}` for each column

Comment: Remove `c` columns and center contents in `m` columns as suggest @koleygr . Of-topic: rules from `booktabs` package doesn't work well with vertical lines.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As explained in the comments, `booktabs` was designed to  avoid using vertical rules in tables: as it adds some padding around horizontal lines, they normally cannot intersect vertical lines. I propose to replace `booktabs` with package `\boldline` which defines variable thickness horizontal and vertical lines. Padding of horizontal lines can be emulated  with the `cellspace`package,which defines a minimal vertical spacing at the top and bottom of cells in columns with specifier prefixed with the letter `S` (or `C` if you load `siunitx`). So here is what I propose:

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\usepackage{array}
\usepackage{boldline}
\usepackage{cellspace}
\setlength{\cellspacetoplimit}{4pt}
\setlength{\cellspacebottomlimit}{4pt}

\begin{document}

\begin{frame}
\centering
\begin{tabular}{V{2} *{4}{>{\centering\arraybackslash}S{m{10mm}} | }S{m{10mm}}V{2}}
\hlineB{2}
foo &
bar &
baz &
qux &
end \\
\hline
foo bar baz qux &
foo bar baz qux &
foo bar baz qux &
foo bar baz qux &
foo bar baz qux \\
\hlineB{2}
\end{tabular}
\end{frame}

\end{document}
```

[image]